# update div asynchronously ---update comments

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have a textarea as below

```
@Html.TextArea("txtComments", new {@style = "width: 450px;",@placeholder = "Enter Comments here" })
```

and when user hits add am saving(user entered comments and time)  to DB using JQUERY AJAX.

After this i need to show the data in div above the textarea whatever user entered with time and also previous comments.

How can i implement this in mvc razor.

Which will similar sort of FB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add the comments to where ever you want in the ajax success call back like

```
$(function(){
 $("#asd").click(function(e){    
    e.preventDefault();
    var $comment = $("textarea").val();   
    console.log($comment);
    //send comments to the server for saving
    //and in the success callback add the comments to the div like
    $.ajax({
        url:'/echo/json/',
        success:function(data){
            $("<li/>",{text:$comment}).appendTo("#commentsss ul");
        }
    });
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rM39e/8/

Comment: do not update the timestamp asynchronously it will eat up alot of resources but still if you want to have a look at "long polling", comit/ server push etc

Comment: how ll i show the previously entered comments in MVC ? tat particular section. any links

Answer (score 0):

Create one partial view which will accept the entityId and will return its comment in sorted order.
Then use a client side javascript to load that partial views on demand or by certain time interval..

If you want this to be done on demand, just use $.get to load the comments in the any container Div.

refer this : [jQuery $.Get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

```
e.g. $("#comments").get({...})
```